# ASP.NET Core Identity prevent user from using same password

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, change-password

I have a project where I am using ASP.NET Core Identity (with IdentityServer4) for user authentication.

When I use `ChangePasswordAsync` to change password, it is allowing the new password to be the same as the current password. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Share your code that is being used to change your password.

Comment: you could implement in the controller, if there's one, to prevent old password == new password.
If you would like to implement on identity API itself, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787120 . Moreover, i believe you might be intereseted in password reuse policy, for your reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065429/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783202/

Comment: I was trying to avoid implementing password validator, but as I see now, there's no other option but using it.

Comment: Thank you very much for extra resources.

Comment: using old password == new password. is not  an option because it will compare the two passwords without validating the password. so if the user enters a random word(not the correct password) in current and new password, a warning will be shown, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: In my opinion, you could create a custom password validator and use JS ajax to call the server validator.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom password validator in which you can do a Login-Request with username + the new password.

If this Login is successful then the password hasn't changed.